# Vscode golang extention takes long time on format

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gofmt

These are the configs on which I run the vscode and golang:

- go version go1.14.1 linux/amd64
- vscode version 1.43.2
- ms-codego version 0.13.1
- Linux/amd64

When I want to save a file with go extension it takes a long time on formatting

```
Saving 'get_ads_for_sites.go': Running 'Go' Formatter ([configure](command:workbench.action.openSettings?%5B%22editor.formatOnSave%22%5D)).)
```

I try `gofmt` and `goimports` and also `goreturns` all of them have this problem. It sometimes takes about 5 minutes and after that it does not do anything. But when I run the go fmt (for example) for that file in the command line, it prints out the formatted result very soon.
It will be ok after a while and then with closing and reopening vscode the problem again raise.

**More info**

When I open another go project I don't have the same problem. I just have the very problem with the told project.
The main difference between these two projects is that in the correct project I am using `go-dep` and in the wrong project I am using `go-mod`

Comment: Have you tried updating the go tools from Vscode?

Comment: I've just tried the option to update the Go tools with VSCode by pressing Shift-Cmd-P and selecting Go: Install/Update tools and then select all available choices for updating or installing. But after reloading VsCode the problem remains. @icza

Comment: @icza please check new info I added in the question